# Where can I upload my commercial app?

Tags: deb

After I found out that its not possible to set a price for an app which has been packaged with SNAP I have followed these [instructions](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/publish/other-forms-of-submitting-apps/publish-commercial-app/) to create a Debian package.
Where can I now upload my debian package?

Comment: The instruction has a link to `myapps` signup. https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/dev/account/

Comment: When I follow the link there is only one option to browse my debian packages. And there comes the following message:
"You have not submitted any debian packages of your applications. All new applications to the store should be packaged as snap packages"

Comment: I suggest writing an E-mail to Canonical for clarification.